# How to display a control for a color property in Storybook?

Tags: angular, storybook

I'm using StoryBook v6.5 with Angular 12 and I have a Bar Graph component which will display values with this kind of parameter:

```
export const BarGraph1 = Template.bind({});
BarGraph1.args = {
  chartData: [
    {
      key: 'completed',
      label: 'Received',
      value: 5,
      color: '#3B3B98',
      child: [
        {
          key: 'readAcknowledged',
          label: 'Acknowledged',
          value: 6,
          color: null,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: 'remaining',
      label: 'Not received',
      value: 10,
      color: '#CED4DA',
    }
  ]
};
```

Unfortunately the "color" sub-property is not displayed with a color picker, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify which type of control you want with the color to be. A simple example would be this:

```
BarGraph1.args = {
  color: '#3B3B98'
};
BarGraph1.argTypes = {
  color: {
    control: {type: 'color' }
  }
}
```

This gives a color picker in the panel.

Comment: Sorry but no, it does not change anything, I tried both :
BarGraph1.argTypes = {
  chartData: {
    color: {
      control: { type: 'color' }
    }
  }
};

BarGraph1.argTypes = {
  color: {
    control: { type: 'color' }
  }
};

Comment: I tried this and it worked